# How does power attack interact with multiple attacks from a high BAB?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats, attack

Let's say that I'm a level 13 bloodrager with +13/+8/+3 BAB.  When I make a full attack, do I calculate the effects of Power Attack on each attack that I make, or only the first one?

Just to make sure, with my total attack bonus being +26/+21/+16 from str+magic weapon, my to-hit and +damage from each blow from using power attack would total to:

+22 to hit, +9 damage
+18 to hit, +7 damage
+15 to hit, +3 damage?

Thanks in advance.  If I'm being confusing with how I'm wording this let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat---final) applies to all or no attacks that round (and until right before your next turn), as described in the feat (though you can "turn on" the ability before making any attack roll, so you could make some attacks without it and then turn it on for later attacks, if you really wanted to, but you can't turn it off again till your next turn).

If you have a BAB of +13 then the Power Attack applies -4 to hit, +8 to damage (adjusting for weapon weight category) to all your attacks.

The BAB charts list the attack bonus for your iterative attacks but that's deceptive - your BAB is +13. Your iterative attacks have the bonuses +13/+8/+3 but that doesn't affect the power attack application.

Answer (score 4):

mxyzplk's answer is mostly correct.  It can apply to all, none, **or just the attacks following turning Power Attack on**.

To add to his answer, you can turn Power Attack on between iterative attacks.  The language "You must choose to use this feat before making an attack roll" is worded so that you can't look at the die result and then determine if you want to use power attack.

You can take your first attack at normal BAB, then choose to turn power attack on for the following.  There are some situations where this is useful.  If you can only hit your first attack on a natural 18+, then you probably don't want to power attack.  But that means your following attacks are only going to hit on a natural 20 so there's no reason to not turn on Power Attack at that point.

If "You must choose to use this feat before making an attack roll" meant only the first attack of the round it would have to say so, but it doesn't.  A very literal (and very wrong) reading of this would also mean that a character could only Power Attack on his first attack ever (obviously that's wrong..).